# Решение уравнений высших степений

Tags: алгоритм, математика, факторизация

Прошу подсказать алгоритм для поиска корней уравнения высшей степени. Конкретней: есть многочлен вида `k[0] * x^n + k[1] * x ^ (n - 1) + ... + k[n - 1] k[i] принадлежит Z и |k[i]| <= 10^9`.Известно, что все корни целые.

Comment: Перебор годится?

Comment: По-моему, для степеней выше 4 алгоритма нет

Comment: @Qwertiy Забыл упомянуть коэффициенты до 10^9 по модулю.

Comment: @Yurich Он точно существует (но я его не знаю)

Comment: @Yurich, алгоритмов нахождения точного решения алгоритмически нет, но алгоритмы поиска корней программно есть. Причём, есть приближённые и есть отдельный метод для целых.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Все целые корни многочлена с целыми коэффициентами являются делителями его свободного члена. 
Поэтому есть такой путь:
 1. Провести [факторизацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) свободного члена.
 2. Найти все делители свободного члена как произведения его простых множителей (взятых в степенях не выше, чем в каноническом разложении),  со знаками плюс и минус.
 3. Отобрать все корни среди делителей.

На самом деле главная проблема - в нахождении одного корня `x=a`, поскольку в соответствии с теоремой Безу многочлен разделится на `x-a`, и следующий корень можно будет подставлять в частное. При этом повторная факторизация также получается путём несложного пересчёта.

Answer (score 0):

> То, что корни общего уравнения пятой степени[en] и выше не выражаются при помощи рациональных функций и радикалов от коэффициентов, было доказано норвежским математиком Нильсом Абелем в 1826 году.

- взято из Википедии.
  Это я имел ввиду когда говорил что алгоритма нет.

Это вовсе не значит что корни можно найти, например подбором, или графическим методом (если они есть).

Comment: Это про выражение в виде формул, но не про поиск корней. Тем более, целочисленных.

Answer (score 0):

Перебираем все корни по небольшим простым модулям, затем используем китайскую теорему об остатках для получения самих корней уравнения (произведение модулей должно быть достаточно большим).

Comment: Поподробней, если можно

Comment: @fellzo, http://e-maxx.ru/algo/chinese_theorem